# Audio not working properly

Tags: drivers, sound, hardware, audio-sync

I've been using my current Ubuntu installation for several months. However yesterday I noticed that the audio was not working properly. 
Whenever I play a video on Youtube, the sound keeps breaking off intermittently. Sometimes is plays out of sync with the video and sometimes at twice the normal speed.

At first I thought it was a browser problem but I noticed the same symptoms when playing a file in VLC Media Player.

This is the result of `sudo aplay -l`:
 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

```
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC268 Analog [ALC268 Analog] Subdevices: 1/1 Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I've checked all the drivers and packages and they're all fine and restarted more than a 100 times (literally!).

What could be the problem?

Comment: Could you give us information about your audio devices?

Answer (score 0):

[wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer)

> PulseAudio controls underlying ALSA-level volume controls. To change
>   the ALSA-level volume controls directly, you can do the following:
>
> Open a terminal. (The quickest way is the `Ctrl`-`Alt`-`T` shortcut.)
>       Enter `alsamixer` and press the Enter key.
>       You will now see a user interface. In this user interface, you can do the following:
>           Select your correct sound card using F6 and select F5 to see recording controls as well
>           Move around with left and right arrow keys.
>           Increase and decrease volume with up and down arrow keys.
>           Increase and decrease volume for left/right channel individually with `Q`, `E`, `Z`, and `C` keys.
>           Mute/Unmute with the `M` key. An `MM` means muted, and `QQ` means unmuted.
>           Exit from alsamixer with the Esc key.
>
> A caveat here: When you mute or unmute something, pulseaudio might
>   pick it up and mute and unmute other controls, as well as PulseAudio's
>   main mute.
>
> If you discover that you need to do something special here to make
>   your sound work, it is likely a bug. Please report a bug using the
>   `ubuntu-bug audio` command. Thanks!